# Saving Eclipse configuration online

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse (Luna) for learning Java and Android. I've installed some plugins (e.g. FindBugs) in my Eclipse IDE. I want to know if it is possible to save my Eclipse configuration (from my current computer) online, so that next time if I have to install Eclipse on some other machine, I can re-use my configuration and automatically get the plugins installed?

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fmulti_user_installs.html) describes how to do a multi-user install. Read it to find out how to configure eclipse so that it saves its configuration files to a specific folder. Then setup Google Drive, and let eclipse save its configuration into a synched folder.

This way, you can have the same configuration on multiple computers & have it ready for new computers.

Answer (score 0):

You can export your prefernces from eclipse, save it on disk, and then import in your new eclipse installation.

```
File->Export->Other->Prefernces
```

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse go to `File -> Export -> Install -> Installed Software Items to File` and upload the resulting file to a FTP, Dropbox, etc.

Then in a new instalation download the file and go to `File -> Import -> Install -> Install Software Items from File`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have a global epf - eclipse preferences file which the eclipse generates to the scm which your project is using. Add a file in your Git, or svn repo or whatever you are using.